# New Workflow manager & Service Bus Farm Configuration Error

Tags: sharepoint-2013, servicebus, workflow-manager-1.x

I am trying to setup a new Workflow manager & Service Bus Farm in my local machine. and in the stage of Create a new service bus farm getting error as "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'" .

Please suggest any resolution.

**Specification :-**
SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition,
Workflow manager 1.0 refresh(CU2)+CU5,
Service Bus 1.1 CU1,
Windows fabric 1.0.970.0

**Error Screenshot :-**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark sure to run the Workflow Manager with a domain account.

A blog ("Farm Creation" section) lists this similar issue for your reference:
[Fun With Installing Service Bus for Windows](https://curtisbadke.ca/blog/2015/10/18/fun-with-installing-service-bus-for-windows/)

Also there is a TechNet blog which lists tips for Successful Installation of Workflow Manager, you can have a look at [it](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33952.sharepoint-2013-2016-2019-tips-for-successful-installation-of-workflow-manager.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue when configuring SharePoint Workflow manager. I added the workflow service account to the local administrators group, also I used Builtin\Administrators in "Workflow Admin Group" field, the problem solved.